# Node.js DNS reverse

Tags: node.js, dns

First, I get the `www.google.com` ip address through `ping www.google.com`.

And then I want to reverse DNS query using Node.js:

```
dns.reverse('172.217.25.4', (err, hostnames) => {
  console.log(hostnames)
})
```

And after run the codes, the terminal print something like `[ 'hkg07s24-in-f4.1e100.net' ]`.

So my question is: **What's `hkg07s24-in-f4.1e100.net`? Why is not www.google.com? Why I can't visit google homepage when I enter `hkg07s24-in-f4.1e100.net` in browser?**

Any response will be appreciated.

Comment: My immediate guess is that the appropriate class A entry or the CNAME or the NS lookup for the new dns reversed has to be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many services (websites) can run on one server/ipaddress (in this case `www.google.com` is one of them), and many hostnames can resolve to one IP address (again, `www.google.com` is one of them, and `hkg07s24-in-f4.1e100.net` also resolves to `172.217.25.4`). 
In the other direction, one ip address will most often resolve to only one hostname (if it has PTR record at all), and the name will very often be something generic like `ip-xx-yy-zz-qq.networkcarrier.net` (so unrelated to any of the services that are legitimately running on that server).

When you use `HTTP`, from your browser, since there are meny sites/sites running on that one IP address, webserver will use the exact hostname as you entered it in address bar to determine which site to show. In this case, webserver is configured to respond with Google home page if request's `Host` HTTP header (which contains hostname as entered in address bar) is `www.google.com` or `172.217.25.4`, but not if it is `hkg07s24-in-f4.1e100.net`